# how do you use svg in drawable folder?

Tags: android, svg

i am creating a bottom navigation bar for a android app following [this](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0) guide

however, when using svg in `android:icon` and building it, it shows a error

> Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

i found out that i needed to move the svg to the assets folder. but if i move it, i can't use the svg... any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Add your XML code as well in question

Comment: You can't use SVG vectors directly, You need to convert them to android XML drawable.

Comment: File -> New -> Vector Asset -> Local file ((SVG/PSD) ->select your svg file

Comment: thank you @AswinPAshok , that solved the problem. sorry i can't upvote you as i do not have more than 15 reputation

Comment: That's alright. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 19):

The answer above gives a link to convert pictures from SVG to XML, but this tool is not for free(only for one SVG file)

So why not to use ANDROID build-in tool?

The best way is to go to res-> drawable-> Vector Asset -> Local file (SVG, PSD) ->select your SVG file from the place you save it.
and you are done :)

Answer (score 2):

Android uses vector drawables which are xml files rather than SVG's.

You will have to convert the SVG to a vector drawable.  Many ways of doing it but a handy web tool is available [here](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/).

It won't do complex SVG's but copes with the majority.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, however i found Aswin P Ashok's answer more easier (sorry for being lazy haha)